# How to keep sort items in CheckedListBox after add and remove items?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox

I’m trying  to add and remove items dynamically from the Items collection and in the end also maintain a numerical order (not alphabetically).

I know the use of:

```
myCheckedListBox.Sorted = true;
```

But it does not perform sorting after the first time, and also sorting is done in an alphabetically and non-numerical way.

```
List<int> lstNumbers = GetListOfNumbers();

//Remove items that need to be deleted 
var itemsForDelete = myCheckedListBox.Items.OfType<int>().Where(chkList => !lstNumbers.Any(num => num == chkList)).ToList();
foreach (int item in itemsForDelete)
    myCheckedListBox.Items.Remove(item);

//Add items that need to be added
foreach (int item in lstNumbers)
if (!myCheckedListBox.Items.Contains(item))
    myCheckedListBox.Items.Add(item);

//Sort timebases list
myCheckedListBox.Sorted = true;
```

The final collection is accepted in GetListOfNumbers() but since I want to keep the checked\unchecked state of previous items, I cannot clear the items and only add the items in lstNumbers

Which way this can be done effectively?

Comment: It is really difficult for me to understand what you are trying to achieve.
You get a lot of items, then you have a list in a UI where things are checked and unchecked? What is your idea then?

Would it be an idea to "save" the content of myCheckedListBox.Items in a temp List and then you can do what ever you want and then use the temp list again later?

Sorry that I don't understand your question properly.

Comment: You're right, it's probably a little unclear.
There is an additional checklistbox, which each item selection adds numbers to mychecklistbox. Since I want to keep status (checked items), and keep the check for the numbers already marked before, I can't always clear all and add the new final list of numbers.

Comment: Did you try myCheckedListBox.Refresh?

Comment: Yes I tried, and there is no change. My problem starts with the fact that sorting is done in an alphabetically and non-numerical way. How to deal with it?